# NullPointerException at (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:104)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting the following stack trace when I try to run my code from main method.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.koushik.javabrains.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<clinit>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:104)
    ... 1 more
```

here is the code.

```
FileSystemResource newResource = new FileSystemResource("spring.xml");
    BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(newResource);
    Triangle triangle = (Triangle) factory.getBean("triangle");
    triangle.draw();
```

Can anyone please tell me why I get this exception and How do I resolve it? 
error is thrown at first line (FileSystemResource newResource = new FileSyste....)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: make sure that spring.xml is in correct location

Comment: Let's see your `DrawingApp` class. It seems you are using a `static` initializer block incorrectly.

Comment: And post the full stack trace and the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ApplicationContext` instead:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
```

But, of course, you have to provide correct config file location: seems to me full path.